# Create an old bootable USB Stick Sierra or High Sierra on a brand new Mac with Catalina

Tags: macos, imac, catalina, bootable-disk

All I need is just an install media for sierra or high sierra. Sound's easy but unfortunately isn't.

I have a MacBook Pro 13" with the latest Catalina installed (10.15.3). To download High Sierra through the App Store is not possible, but luckily I got the Sierra dmg from here: https://support.apple.com/de-de/HT208202

The Target-System is an iMac 2011. The HDD is empty.

I already tried the Internet-Recovery on the iMac with the option to install macOS Lion, but this end up with an -2 million days error. I thought it might be an error about the datetime and certificates, so I also changed the date back to somewhere in 2012. Anyway the internet-recovery was not successful.

So my next try was to create a simple bootable stick with Sierra as mentioned before. All I have is latest MacBook 13" with latest Catalina installed. After copying the Sierra Install App to the Application Folder I tried the following command:

`sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Sierra --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app`

But this ends up with nearly freezing my MacBook and ends with an exception:

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff39dbf8ab __exceptionPreprocess + 250
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff70079805 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x00007fff3c48bdb5 -[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:error:] + 5014
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff3c4b55d5 +[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:arguments:] + 153
    4   createinstallmedia                  0x0000000107a41968 createinstallmedia + 6504
    5   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff713e77fd start + 1
    6   ???                                 0x0000000000000005 0x0 + 5
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I am at a loss of how to get this old iMac running again. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try downloading  [High Sierra](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208969)? I did this on a 2013 iMac. Used the instructions [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) to transfer to a flash drive. I did not have any problems using the flash drive to install High Sierra on the same iMac.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Downloading high sierra on my MacBook Pro with Catalina is not possible. This is a App-Store Link. A click on "Load" inside of the App-Store ends up with opening the System-Update window and tells me thats a wrong version.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm finding it impossible to install a more modern OS version on my 2010 Mac Mini when it used to run High Sierra fine. Stuck on Lion, my laptop is Catalina also.

Comment: No, I didn't found an official solution. The easiest way is to ask a friend with an old cd or to buy a prepared usb-stick somewhere. But you can contact me over one of my social media accounts and I can help you to get an valid image :)